# When applying for an ESTA do I have to say I have another nationality?

Tags: esta, dual-nationality

My parents are Turkish Cypriot, but I was born in the UK and both parents had British passports at that time as well. I only view myself as a British citizen and not Turkish. I view my nationality as only being British.

So during the ESTA application, they ask if I have any other nationality. I just say no right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68501/discussion-on-question-by-gully0923-when-applying-for-an-esta-do-i-have-to-say-i).

Answer (score 19):

To answer the question : **Yes you have to declare all your citizenships on the ESTA application.** The question is about legalities, and it doesn't matter what you 'regard yourself' as.

You should investigate whether you have Turkish citizenship. If it turns out that you do, you should declare it. It probably is going to have no effect on your ESTA application.

It's also worth pointing out that most countries allow you to renounce a citizenship, so that's an option if you find you have a citizenship you don't want.

Comment: Is it possible to renounce Turkish citizenship? And if it is possible at all, can you do it if you have ever applied for a passport?

Comment: @Willeke it is in general possible to renounce Turkish nationality, and as far as I can tell passport applications are not relevant to that possibility, but a man apparently cannot renounce without having completed compulsory military service or obtaining a deferment or paying an exemption fee.  I couldn't find information from the Turkish government in English, but the Dutch government does have [information about this in English](https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-nationality/question-and-answer/can-i-renounce-my-turkish-nationality-if-i-haven-t-completed-my-compulsory-military-service)

Comment: i spoke to local travel agent who is also turkish who said i am just british and thats it no matter what my father is etc. I even said he owns a turkish passport and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare **both current and past citizenship** on the ESTA Application.  So, it doesn't matter if you renounced or how you view yourself.

From the ESTA Application:

> Are you now, a citizen or national of any other country?
>
> Have you ever been a citizen or national of any other country?

Seems that if either of your parents were Turkish citizens at your birth, Turkey claims you as a citizen, event though they may not even know about you.  Ask your parents if they have proof renouncing their Turkish citizenship, then *consult a lawyer specializing in US immigration policy.*

Comment: spoke to a travel agent (turkish airlines) she said no you r british makes no differences on me if your parents own turkish passports and so forth i’m only a british citizen born here! and only own a UK passport . Which is what i assumed in the first place. its like if that was the cases i would be allowed to go turkey /north Cyprus without a passport soon as though simply because of my dad i am a citizen. rubbish.